# Select the top child of a top child for each record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given these tables:

```
GroupA,

GroupB(with a FK to GroupA.Id),

GroupC (with a FK to GroupB.Id and Image.Id),

Image
```

I'm trying and failing with nested selects to loop through each Group A, select the first GroupB with a matching FK, select the first Group C of the Group B, and then Select a field from the Images table.

This is for a web page where I will output the following for each GroupA

```
<h2>GroupA.Title...

<img src=Images.ImageUrl...
```

but to do that I need to pull the Top GroupB which pulls the Top Group C which gets the Image on an Inner Join.

I'm pretty sure nested selected are not the way forward (the first nested statement works, but not the next one which uses the result of the first nested statement). Can someone point me in the right direction please? I'm sure there's a proper way to do this.

Edit: Sample Data structure

```
GroupA {GroupAId,Title}

GroupB {GroupBId,FKGroupAId}

GroupC {GroupCId,FKGroupBId, FKImageId}

Image {ImageId,ImageUrl}
```

So....
If they were separate queries I could

Select * from GroupA - and loop through GroupA and select a single Top 1 GroupB where GroupB.FKGroupAId = GroupA.GroupAId;

I would then Select the Top 1 Group C where GroupC.FKGroupBID = GroupB.GroupBId with an innerjoin on Image.

That's 2 selects for each GroupA Image I want to get = too many.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: how are you ordering the rows in groups b and c?  is there an independent sort field, or do you want the max(b.id) and max(c.id)?

Comment: @Beth - Any record from B and C will do. I was just going to choose the Top record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this do what you want?

```
SELECT a.Id, (
    SELECT TOP 1 i.myColumn
    FROM GroupB b 
    INNER JOIN GroupC c ON b.id = c.bId
    INNER JOIN Image i ON c.imageid = i.id
    WHERE a.id = b.aId
    ORDER BY b.id, c.id
) AS myColumn
FROM GroupA a
```

There's probably an even better way to do it without a subquery too.